Relative file sizes of WebP and JPEG XL (lossless vs. lossy)
I just tested lossless and lossy encoding of a PNG screenshot and was surprised by the relativ file sizes:
# lossless transcoding
$ cjxl -d 0 screenshot.png screenshot.jxl
$ avifenc --lossless screenshot.png screenshot.avif
$ cwebp -lossless screenshot.png -o screenshot.webp

# lossy transcoding
$ cjxl screenshot.png screenshot_lossy.jxl
$ avifenc screenshot.png screenshot_lossy.avif
$ cwebp screenshot.png -o screenshot_lossy.webp

$ ls -la screenshot*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 snafu  staff   109K Oct 25 11:20 screenshot.avif
-rw-r--r--@ 1 snafu  staff    42K Oct 25 11:01 screenshot.jxl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 snafu  staff   145K Sep  1 20:13 screenshot.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 snafu  staff    33K Oct 25 11:14 screenshot.webp
-rw-r--r--@ 1 snafu  staff    23K Oct 25 11:25 screenshot_lossy.avif
-rw-r--r--@ 1 snafu  staff    65K Oct 25 11:26 screenshot_lossy.jxl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 snafu  staff    40K Oct 25 11:25 screenshot_lossy.webp

Why are the lossless versions for WebP and JPEG XL smaller than their lossy counterparts?
